# Adding named parameters in express route api

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express route that looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/v1/username/:option', function(req, res) {

  // do stuff

})
```

How can I modify this route so that the URL show the parameter name of option (`option=`)? For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/johndoe/option=my-cool-option
```

Answer (score 18):

That's a URL segment, not a parameter.

If you want it like you've shown the URL, it'd be

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/johndoe/?option=my-cool-option
```

Note the question mark `?`, this specifies that it's a GET parameter.

```
app.get('/api/v1/:username', function(req, res) {
    //req.params.username would equal 'johndoe'
    //req.query.option would equal 'my-cool-option'
})
```