# get method with colon and question mark in server path

Tags: node.js, express

Follow up question: What is the code "res.json(false);" doing? Doesn't that print out false on the page instead of showing the data I want?

I'm looking at the following sample code. I understand that `.get(` is the method and `/:characters?` is the server path. In this search, what is the point of the colon and the question mark in the path? Shouldn't the question mark come before characters because it is a query?

```
app.get('/:characters?', function (req, res) {
    var chosen = req.params.characters;

    if (chosen) {
        console.log(chosen);

        for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            if (chosen === characters[i].routeName) {
                res.json(characters[i]);
                return;
            }
        }

        res.json(false);
    } else {
        res.json(characters);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding named parameters in express route api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804458/adding-named-parameters-in-express-route-api)

Answer (score 5):

In this case the question mark signifies an optional parameter "characters".  This allows for an endpoint that MAY have a value or not.  They are then testing against that parameter to see if it was included. If so they will iterate through the "characters" object and return any matching entry to the endpoint the user specified.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer:

`:XXX` means that its a URL parameter. (i.e. `req.params.XXX` will pick up what the XXX is)

`?` means that the parameter is optional. (i.e. the client-side user doesn't *need* to include this parameter in the url).

So:

`/:characters?` would allow for: both `/` AND `/yoda` to hit this route.

Answer (score 1):

`:characters` isn't actually part of the query string. It will be part of the url.

The url will be something similar to the following (assuming you are running this server locally and on port `8080`):

`http://localhost:8080/abcdefg`

And in that case, `req.params.characters` will be `'abcdefg'`

Putting an explicit question mark in the route definition is a mistake, in my opinion. I'm not entirely sure what purpose that question mark would serve.

For the follow up question, what it appears to be doing is looking for a match in the `characters` variable (which I assume is defined externally) by `characters[i].routeName`, and returning the found value. If no value is found, that's when it sends back `false` (or tries to - to be honest, I'm not sure what express will do if you try using `res.json(false)`, since I'm not sure `false` is valid JSON).

Answer (score -1):

This is a normal case that a endpoint or a resource can contain a variable that means

lets take facebook for example so if you see the timeline of MarkZukerberg then the endpoint or url is

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck
```

if you see your own profile then that zuck will be replaced by your name. so the name parameter here is a variable.

When ever a variable is a part of the url then we precede that with a colon sign in express syntax

and if we want to send some other values as the query parameter then we use ? mark to tell the server that the following string will be a query parameter

`?name=value&age=12&gender=male`

And

```
res.json(false)
```

will just return false as the response nothing else